# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1055 , group by substring

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

**Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'shows.b.show_title' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by**

```
SELECT b.show_title as show_title FROM `shows` `b` 
WHERE `b`.`active` = 1 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(show_title, 1, 1)
```

I'm naming all columns in select query so why the error?

I know the workaround of disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from sql_mode but how do i solve the error with the query?

Comment: Your query makes little sense. You want an effectively random title chosen for each letter of the alphabet that has an active title that starts with that letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Q: why the error?*

Consider two rows with show_title values of 'True Detective' and 'True Lies'

The expression in the GROUP BY is going to return `T` for both of those rows, so those rows are going to be collapsed into a single row in the resultset.

The query can return only a single value for a column in the collapsed row, and it's indeterminate/ambiguous which of the two values to return. With ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in sql_mode, MySQL is adhering more closely to the ANSI SQL specification; the 1055 error is behavior similar to what we observe in other relational DBMS e.g. Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, Teradata, DB2, et al.

---

*Q: how do i solve the error with the query?*

The normative pattern is to use an aggregate function to specify which value (out of a set of possible values) to return.

For example, `MAX()` or `MIN()`. Demonstration:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(b.show_title,1,1)    AS s1 
     , MAX(b.show_title)           AS max_show_title
     , MIN(b.show_title)           AS min_show_title
  FROM shows b
 WHERE b.active = 1
 GROUP BY SUBSTR(b.show_title,1,1)
```

will avoid the 1055 error, and could return e.g.

```
s1  max_show_title   min_show_title
--  ---------------  ---------------
T   True Lies        True Detective
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use these two queries and run them as query.
Your problem will be fixed asap.
No need to restart mysql

solution :
run this query :

1. SET sql_mode = '';
2. SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));